# Does not want to resize columns in Flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, flexigrid

I want to disable column resizing in Flexigrid.
Is there any option like colresize:false/true ? I could not find any.

Comment: try `resizable: false` refer to http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/

Comment: I just checked it. It enables/disables resizing of the whole grid, not columns.

Comment: Then I think there no option in flexigrid to resize column. I have created an issue here https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/issues/9 keep track of it if they resolve it.

Comment: cool. Thanks. I used @Nildarar method and it worked.

Comment: Good. Does it worked without modification? If so I'll use the same method if needed in future

Comment: yes. It worked without modification. Though there were few css related problems which were minor and I tweaked them according to my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I found this:

change beginning of dragStart to:

```
if (dragtype=='colresize' && p.colResize == true) //column resize
{
    $(g.nDiv).hide();$(g.nBtn).hide();
    var n = $('div',this.cDrag).index(obj);
    var ow = $('th:visible div:eq('+n+')',this.hDiv).width();
    $(obj).addClass('dragging').siblings().hide();
    $(obj).prev().addClass('dragging').show();
    this.colresize = {startX: e.pageX, ol: parseInt(obj.style.left), ow: ow, n : n };
    $('body').css('cursor','col-resize');
    //cleanup
    n=null;
    ow=null;
}
```

To make it cleaner you can add a property to pass in like colResize:true, but set colResize:false as a default in flexigrid. And then check p.colResize == true to enable resizing.  This way you can have it both ways when needed.  Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

`colResize: false`   property will disable the option.