# I want to disable column resizing for n number columns in colResize plugin

Tags: jquery, resize, drag

I am using the colResize jquery plugin for my app. You can find this here http://quocity.com/colresizable/.

Now I want to disable dragging **n** number of columns, is there any way?

I saw the same kind of question on stack overflow at
[Does not want to resize columns in Flexigrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615453/does-not-want-to-resize-columns-in-flexigrid)

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In the stack overflow question you linked to, one of the comments linked to [an issue on github)[https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/issues/9] for adding the ability to disable column resizing. It looks like [that issue was fixed 11 months ago](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/commit/193a18b5661872a4ccd6f35ed9b072dcc2c26e15) and [merged into Flexigrid 9 months ago](https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/pull/66), and there is now a check for `colResize == true` in the `dragStart` function.

Have you tried setting `colResize` to false on the columns that you don't want to be draggable?